# NSTableview selection jerking

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

I have created a desktop based application in mac os x 10.6. The app uses `NSTableview` for listing files. I use the mouse click for table selection. The code used is

```
[tableView selectRowIndexes:ind byExtendingSelection:NO];
```

`ind` is the `indexset`.
When i select files one by one using mouse click, i find a small jerking effect each time when i click the row of the table. Can anyone suggest a method to avoid the jerking effect.

Here is the code

```
- (void) clickedIt:(id)sender{
    id indexsett = [[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexSet: [subviewTableView selectedRowIndexes]];
    if([indexsett count] <=1)
    {
        if  ([self isValidDelegateForSelector:@selector(tableView:shouldClickedRow:)])
        {
            [delegate  tableView:subviewTableView  shouldClickedRow:(int)[subviewTableView  selectedRow]];
        }
    }else
    {
        [indexsett enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger  idx, BOOL  *stop) {
            NSLog(@"tracing index:%ld",idx);
            [delegate tableView:subviewTableView shouldClickedRow:(int)idx];
        }];
    }
}

- (BOOL) tableView:(NSTableView *) tableView shouldClickedRow:(int) row
{
    if(row != -1) {
        if([ind count]>0) {
            if([ind containsIndex:row]) {
                [ind removeIndex:row];            
                [tableView selectRowIndexes:ind byExtendingSelection:NO];
            }else {
                [ind addIndex:row];
                [tableView selectRowIndexes:ind byExtendingSelection:NO];
            }
        }else {
            [ind addIndex:row];
            [tableView selectRowIndexes:ind byExtendingSelection:NO];
        }
        return YES;
    }else{
        [tableView selectRowIndexes:ind byExtendingSelection:NO];
    }    
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: If you are using the mouse for selection, why are you setting the selection in code? Are you doing some kind of file I/O when the selections changes that would cause the delay?

Comment: @FrancisMcGrew- i am not doing any i/o. when i click s row, i save the  corresponding index to "ind" and use the above said code.

Comment: That method sets the index -- try removing it. If you want to get the current selection you can call `selectedRowIndexes` at any time. Otherwise you'll have to list more code so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @FrancisMcGrew- i ve put the code in the question itself